# Run SQL Query With Execute-SQLQuery

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to run a SQL Query.  I am hitting 2 errors, and not sure how to resolve.  This is my syntax

```
Function Execute-SQLquery 
{

  $QueryString = "Select employeename, employeeaddress, employeephone from employeefile where et = 'Active'"
  $Date = Get-Date -f 'MM.dd.yy'
  $FilePath = "R:\Test\Testing\"

  $SD = "M:\\CSV\Template\Try.csv"

  $server = "server"
  $database = "db"

  $connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
  $connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
  $conn=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

  $cmd=$conn.CreateCommand()
  $cmd.CommandText = $QueryString   

  $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
  $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
  $rowCount=$SqlAdapter.Fill($dt)

  [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($SD)
  $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $SD -NoTypeInformation


  $connection.Close()
}
```

And here are the errors:

> Can not index into a null aray 
>  $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV $SD - NoTypeInformation
>
> You can not call a method on a null-valued expression
>  $connection.Close()

Comment: What type of database are your querying?  Excel, Access, text, Oracle, Paradox? - It may serve you well to look at these: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @Leptonator Going from SQL Server to a CSV file

Comment: As you can tell, there are quite a few ways to connect..  i would go to the bottom of the page: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and select the version of SQL Server you want to connect to and run with it.

Comment: You never populate `$DataSet`?

Comment: @Mat - when I fill the dt, then use Tables[0] isn't that populating my dataaset?

Comment: `$dt` is not the same as `$dataset`. I think you made a simple typo is my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have two typos here. I will assume it is a result of your code biting ( grabbing snippets from more than one place and putting them together )from the internet to make your solution

- `$dt` is not the same as `$dataset`
- `$conn`  is not the same as `$connection`

In both cases update your script to be using the former.